# Maven Transitive dependency in Webapplication

Tags: maven-3

i have web application A which has dependency on Javaapplication B which has dependency on Javaapplication c  .
i am new to maven . if i change anything in C(not building c) and if i build only A , will the changes done in c automatically compiled and reflected ?

Answer (score 0):

Not automatically, no. If your IDE has all of them open at the same time, it may figure this out for you though.

You can get this functionality (sort of) with Maven itself and submodules. Make a directory to hold all three. The `pom.xml` in the outer directory will just contain a list of modules, which will be in subdirectories, like so:

```
<modules>
  <module>A</module>
  <module>B</module>
  <module>C</module>
</modules>
```

Then you could invoke Maven like so: `mvn -pl A -am package` and it would build C, then B, and then A, having figured out the dependency relationship between those modules and the one you want.

Comment: what does build with dependency mean compared to clean and build option in netbeans ??

Comment: Netbeans probably figured out the dependency relationship and will build things in the correct order for you. If not, try using submodules like I describe, it will force Maven to figure out the order when you build (with or without Netbeans).

Comment: @Adeshshetty want to click the "accept answer" button then?